# How to use a yield expression in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'am trying to use yield expression in python to print the number: 0,2,4 .... with the code but I keep getting as print : `<generator object some_f at 0x000000000252D240>`

the code is:

```
fn= lambda n: 2*n

def Make_iterator(fn):

    def some_f():
        i=0
        yield fn(i)
        i+=1

    return some_f

iterator = Make_iterator(fn)
for i in range(4):
    print(iterator())
```

Comment: Why do you need `Make_iterator` at all? `for i in range(4): print(fn(i))` will print what you want.

Comment: You keep creating a new generator object. Loop *over* the iterator.

Comment: this is the exercise.

Comment: What do you expect to see instead? Your iterator doesn't have any loops, so it'll only yield *one* thing, and then it is done.

Comment: @synt: `i` in the generator and `i` in the `for` loop have no relationship to one another, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more what you are looking for.

```
fn = lambda n: 2*n

def Make_iterator(fn):
    def my_iter():
        i=0
        while i<10:
            yield fn(i)
            i+=1
    return my_iter()


for i in Make_iterator():
    print(i)
```

You don't need the extra function wrapper and you need to make sure you iterate over your iterator, rather than just calling it a bunch of times.

Comment: Its doing the job well , but i allowed to change only the function Make_iterator. So i must to return another function from make_iterator

Comment: It seems odd, but the above should do that?